# Can I create a flat landscape with decaying functions?

Tags: real-analysis

Imagine we have scalar functions $f : \mathbb{R^2}\times \mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that are (at least on average) decreasing in every direction around a point in $\mathbb{R^2}.$ For example
$$
f(\vec{x}, \vec{a_i}) = \left((x_0-a_{i0})^2 + (x_1-a_{i1})^2\right)^{-1}.
$$
Here $\vec{a_i}$ is a given fixed point.
Furthermore we have
$$
F(\vec{x}) = \sum_{i} f(\vec{x}, \vec{a_i})
$$
Does a function $f$ like that exist, such that the following function $F$ is a constant (at least mostly) over some patch of $\mathbb{R^2}$?

If it makes it easier we can asume the $\{\vec{a_i}\}$ produces a infinitely large regular grid over  $\mathbb{R^2}.$

I couldn't make anything work with more than 2 points.

Comment: This is called "partition of unity".

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro THANK you so much!! I'll look into it!

Comment: Did you find what you were looking for? Showing theoretically that a partition of unity exists may be easy, but actually building one can be tricky.